# Tesseract for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ocr, tesseract

Here i like to know about how to implement Tesseract for Unity.

I found a [link](https://github.com/pixelsquare/tesseract-ocr-unity)

But not a sample , they have given a dll, After importing the Dll i have followed the below code but getting some errors,

```
public string GetText(Bitmap imgsource)
{
    var ocrtext = string.Empty;
    using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
    {
        using (var img = PixConverter.ToPix(imgsource))
        {
            using (var page = engine.Process(img))
            {
                ocrtext = page.GetText();
            }
        }
    }

    return ocrtext;
}
```

But getting error like,

> Assets\Scripts\TesseractOCR.cs(20,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

---

> But there is no error in Visual Studio, it shows only in Editior.
>
> I have placed the tesseract plugin and System.drawing plugin inside
>   Assets\Plugins

Any other alternative ways?

Thanks&Regards,

Nandha

Comment: did you copy all the scripts and the folder plugin, from github, into your unity project?

Comment: `After importing the Dll` how exactly did you do that? Did you follow the [Managed plug-ins Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html)?

Comment: @Dom93 Yes, but there are no scripts available in github

Comment: @derHugo let me try

Comment: you should also checkout the [Plugin Inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to use the dll in unity using the github repository, but it seems incompatible, it gives an error that says is compiled in x86 and asks you to compile it in x64. I've seen that you have the option to add tesseract via nuget:

[image]

If the tesseract is the same you can use the nuget package instead of the one that you are trying to use from github.

Comment: I have added from Nuget, but after that there is no error in Visual studio, but in Unity

Comment: Yes same problem here.I think Tesseract dll not getting recognised in unity

Comment: i've had an error saying that tesseract is compiled in x86, and needs to be compiled in x64, if this is the error you will need the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference `System.Drawing.dll` in your solution

Comment: @Nandha, you have to add a reference to it in your project. Have you done that?

Comment: I have updayed my question. There is no error in VS but in the Unity Editor as mentioned in the updated question